# Use custom function for CSS property in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, styled-components, ternary

I use styled components and I want to set the `transform` to:

- value x if condition is true,
- value y if condition 2 is true,
- null if none are true.

I didn't find much information online so I tried something like:

```
const altDirectionFunc = (props) => {
    if (props.altDirection === 'row') {
        return 'translate(30%, -50%)'
    } else if (props.altDirection === 'column') {
        return 'translate(-50%, 30%)'
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
    position: relative; 
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 2.5em;
    background: ${props => props.isChecked ? props.theme : 'transparent'};
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.isChecked ? props.theme : vars.black};
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    border-radius: ${props => props.circular ? '50%' : null};
    &::before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: '${props => props.isChecked ? '\f00c' : null}';
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        line-height: 16px;
    }
    &::after {
        content: '${props => props.altText}';
        opacity: ${props => props.isChecked ? '1' : '0'};
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        color: ${vars.black};
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: max-content;
        transform: '${altDirectionFunc}'; // That's what matters
        font-family: ${vars.mainFont};

    }
`;

//

 <StyledTextField size={size} initalValue={initalValue} onChange={handleChange}
        fontFamily={fontFamily} theme={theme} {...otherProps} value={value} dir={direction}/>
```

However, I don't achive the result I want, there's no difference if I pass `altDirection="row"` or `altDirection="column"`

How can I fix it?

Seems like the transform isn't being called:

[image]

**P.S. I used the ternary operator before, but this is much more clean. Is it not possible to use functions like that or did I made a mistake?**

Comment: Please show a full example. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, show the component which uses `altDirectionFunc`

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Your example does work. Maybe a typo: `transform: ${altDirectionFunc}; // not '${altDirectionFunc}'`, https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-banach-l9oce?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: the ' ' are not there now, but it still doesn't work.. seems like the transform isn't shown in the styles when I use the devtools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like your styled component to call a custom function (ie `altDirectionFunc`) to obtain a value for the `transform` property.

In your case, the syntax of your styling (with `'` around the `altDirectionFunc`) will be causing incorrect styling to be evaluated for your component. Changing that to the following will allow the `altDirectionFunc` to be correctly called when the styled component is evaluated, and should achieve the desired result:

```
transform: ${ (props) => altDirectionFunc(props) };
```

Here's a complete example:

```
const altDirectionFunc = (props) => {
    if (props.altDirection === 'row') {
        return 'translate(30%, -50%)'
    } else if (props.altDirection === 'column') {
        return 'translate(-50%, 30%)'
    } else {
        return 'unset' // Update this
    }
}

const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
    position: relative; 
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 2.5em;
    background: ${props => props.isChecked ? props.theme : 'transparent'};
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.isChecked ? props.theme : vars.black};
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    border-radius: ${props => props.circular ? '50%' : null};
    &::before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: ${props => props.isChecked ? '\f00c' : null}; // Fixed this too
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        line-height: 16px;
    }
    &::after {
        content: ${props => props.altText}; // Fixed this too
        opacity: ${props => props.isChecked ? '1' : '0'};
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        color: ${vars.black};
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: max-content;
        transform: ${ (props) => altDirectionFunc(props) }; // The fix
        font-family: ${vars.mainFont};

    }
`;
```

Comment: seems like the transform isn't shown in the styles when I use the devtools

Comment: strange - are you passing in the `altText` prop as a string? and, did you apply the other fixes shown in my answer?

Comment: That's strange - it should be working in that case. I have a sample of this concept working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-61933527-transform-pjw60 Are you able to cross check your code with this?

Comment: It works now, I changed something and now it's OK. thanks!